# How do i email from php form

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, email

I am trying to insert the name, email, company, phone and country from the array into the email message, but all I get is an empty email.
The subject, to and from all works, but I am not getting the message in the email.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<? php
public function contact_mail() {

    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'company' => $this->input->post('company'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'country' => $this->input->post('country')
    );

    $success = $this->data->save_contact_info($data);
    if ($success) {
        $data = array('success_message' => 'Thank you. We\'ll be in touch.');
        $this->load->view('ajax/json', array('json' => $data));

        $this->load->library('email');
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from("noreply@example.com", "Example Notification Service");
        $this->email->to(array('mha@example.com'));
        $this->email->subject('Contact form');
        $this->email->message($data);
        $this->email->send();

    }
    else {
        $this->load->view('ajax/error', array('error_msg' => 'Please fill out all fields.'));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Turns out it was working, but the message in the email is just "1".

How do i get the email message to be the name, email, company, phone and country from the form?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$this->load->view('ajax/json', array('json' => $data));
```

to this:

```
$view = $this->load->view('ajax/json', array('json' => $data));
```

Then instead of sending `$data` through which is just an `array`, you send through `$view` which is the HTML that includes the array.

Also, you're using `$data` to get all of the `POST` variables, but then use `data` later to set a flash message.

I'm not sure whether you mean to overwrite `$data` or not, but it's always best to keep the variable names different for different things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer